# Javascript return two values in onchange function

Tags: javascript, function, onchange

I need to return two values in a text input.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
<input type="text" size="2" name="disOrd[<? echo $usersArray[$x]['id']; ?>]" 
value="<? echo $usersArray[$x]['disOrd']; ?>" 
onchange="updateAgentOrder(this.name,this.value)" />
```

It only returns the first one, not the second one.  Is this even possible to do?  I absolutely need both.

Here's what updateAgentOrder does, just a temporary deal to get the values:

```
function updateAgentOrder(x,y){
alert(x,y);
}
```

If I change the order of this.name and this.value, it will only show the first one.

Comment: That *should* work, but what is `updateAgentOrder`'s definition?

Comment: ? Now that you posted an example for your `updateAgentOrder` function I doubt that you want to return multiple values from a function as described in your title and question. Do you mean "passing multiple variable into a function" instead?

Comment: Boy do I feel like an idiot :p

Comment: `alert()` only takes one argument, and alerts that value. That's why you're not seeing `y`. Run `alert(x); alert(y);` to prove that `y` is in fact available inside `updateAgentOrange`.

Comment: alert(x+'   '+y); will give you both values in single alert call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alert` only takes one argument, the thing to alert.

```
alert(x);
alert(y);
```

This will show two alerts, one after the other, showing each of the two values.

Comment: Won't let me accept answer yet, but yea you're absolutely right, what was I thinking lol...

Comment: This answer does not answer the question above, but after the last edit of that question it looks like it is correct – even if the OP hasn't asked for it ;-)

Comment: The answer is that my function call is correct and is passing the right values.  The only reason I didn't know that is because I was presenting the passed values incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't create functions with multiple return values in JS. (as in Python or Go) If you need to return multiple values from a function you need to wrap them in a literal object:

```
return {
    name: name,
    value: value
};
```

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes, and the OP is talking about returning multiple values anywhere…

Comment: OP titled the question incorrectly. Reading the question prompted me to ask for the code of `updateAgentOrder`, which clearly showed the source of the problem. That is what comments are for: requesting clarification so that the question may be answered efficiently and *correctly*.